# Find $P$ in the plane of $\triangle ABC$ that minimizes $a\,AP^2+b\,BP^2+c\,CP^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

From KMO:

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle. Find a point $P$ in the plane of $\triangle ABC$ such that $a\,AP^2 + b\,BP^2 + c\,CP^2$ is minimum.

How can I solve this problem by using the basic properties of a triangle?

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ just arbitrary constants or the lengths of the triangle sides?

Comment: a, b, c are the lengths of sides BC, CA and AB respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of lack of information $a,b,c $ will be assumed to be positive real numbers. Let $(x,y)$ be the coordinates of the point $P$. Then the sum in question is:
$$
S=a[(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2]+b[(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2]+c[(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2].
$$

From the two equations:
$$
\frac{dS}{dx}=0;\quad
\frac{dS}{dy}=0,
$$
one obtains that the extremum of $S$ is attained at the point:
$$
x=\frac{ax_A+bx_B+cx_C}{a+b+c};\quad
y=\frac{ay_A+by_B+cy_C}{a+b+c}.\tag1
$$

The equation $(1)$ describes the [barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_point_geometry) of masses $a,b,c$ assigned to vertices $A,B,C$, respectively. In the case $a=b=c$, the point is the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the triangle $ABC$. In the case $a:b:c=BC:CA:AB$ it is the [incenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter) of the triangle.

I left it to you to check that the extremum $(1)$ is indeed the minimum.

Comment: Your formulas for x and y imply that the extremal point is actually the incenter of ABC. (because its barycentric coordinates are [a:b:c])

Comment: That is, when a, b, c are the sides of ABC

Comment: @liaombro I have already asked OP to clarify the issue, but for clarity I will list this possibility as well.